# Use tizen 2.3.X on Samsung Z3 device

Tags: tizen

Currently Samsung Z3 devices use tizen 2.4.X Operating System. But is it possible to downgrade Operating System. 
For example, Can tizen 2.3.X can be used in Samsung Z3 devices??

Comment: As far i know, it is not possible to downgrade OS.

Comment: I have already downgraded tizen OS 2.4.X to tizen 2.3.X in Z1 device. @Iqbalhossain, can you ensure me weather it is device specific?? I mean is downgraded not possible on Z3 device??

Comment: How did you downgrade on that device?

Comment: I have downloaded the firmware file & used Odin v3.09 to downgrade

Comment: As far i know firmware is device specific ... each firmware is released for a particular device.